# Print string from LPSAFEARRAY*

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll

I created a static DLL in C++ which contains a function

```
int _stdcall StringTest(SAFEARRAY** StringArray)
```

and accessing this from a VB project

```vb
<DllImport("VB_TestDLL.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Shared Function StringTest(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType:=VarEnum.VT_BSTR)> ByRef inputArray() As String) As Integer
    End Function
```

My input array from VB is :

```vb
Dim inArray(9) As String

    inArray(0) = "xyz"
    inArray(1) = "abc"
    inArray(2) = "aaaaa"
    inArray(3) = "bbbb"
    inArray(4) = "afassda"
    inArray(5) = "asdsdssss"
    inArray(6) = "ccc"
    inArray(7) = "bbb"
    inArray(8) = "bbbb"
    inArray(9) = "Enfa"
```

In DLL, what I am trying to do is accessing this input array and print string values in file(just to check, later using string I will create a SQL query).
 When I tried following piece of code

```
CComSafeArray<BSTR> sa(*StringArray);
for (int i = 0; i < sa.GetCount(); i++) {
        myfile<< sa.GetAt(i) << std::endl;
}
```

I got output as :

```
01298A34
01298A5C
01298A84
01298AAC
01298AD4
01298B0C
01298B44
01298B6C
01298B94
01298BBC
```

Then I tried `LPSAFEARRAY`* instead of `SAFEARRAY**`

```
char** StrPtr = 0;
    long LowerBound = 0;
    long UpperBound = 0;

    SafeArrayGetLBound(*StringArray,1,&LowerBound);
    SafeArrayGetUBound(*StringArray,1,&UpperBound);

    SafeArrayAccessData(*StringArray, (void**)(&StrPtr));


    myfile << "Input Array Assigned!" << std::endl; //printing in file
    for (LONG i = LowerBound; i <= UpperBound; i++)
    {
            myfile << StrPtr[i] << std::endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
    SafeArrayUnaccessData(*StringArray);
```

and I got following output:

```
x
a
a
b
a
a
c
b
b
E
```

I tried debugging the DLL and found
 [image: this]

I don't know why I am getting L"x" and so on for other entries and unable to print complete strings.

Comment: That's the common outcome when the `<<` operator is mislead by `char**` when it is actually contains utf16-encoded strings.  Using `wchar_t**` ought to make you happier.  Technically you are supposed to use `BSTR*` since such a string may contain embedded zeros, but no happy `<<` overload for that.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you provide a quick snippet for this?